# Check wireless device is up

Tags: bash, variables, wifi

I would like to check if my wireless device is correctly up.

In order to do this, I execute the following command :

```
ip link show wlan0
```

I obtain :

```
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT     group default qlen 1000
   link/ether fc:c2:de:2d:f4:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

when the interface is up and

```
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group     default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:c2:de:2d:f4:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

when it is down.

Now, I would like to test if UP is present or not at the command line return.

I tried the following command :

```
 ip link show mlan0 | awk '/UP/ {print $3}'
```

which gives :

I would now isolate UP but I don't know how to do this step.

At the same time, I am not sure if it is useful to isolate UP. 
Basically, could I execute :

```
var=`ip link show wlan0 | awk '/UP/ {print $3}'`
if [ "$var" == "" ];then
   echo "interface did not up"
else 
   echo "do something else.."
fi
```

thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

Given that you are using `ip link` it is likely you are on Linux. I recommend one of the `/sys/class` hierarchies:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate
up
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier
1
```

The output of `ip link show` is likely to cause grief you if the format changes - I don't think it is guaranteed to remain stable.

---

In light of comments it seems you might want the administrative state (what you told the interface to do) not its actual state - whether it is actually connected. In that case, you might get away with flags:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/flags
0x1003 # (changes to 0x1002 when running ip link set dev wlan0 down)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but I am not sur to understand the Wireless behavior. Indeed, after using the command ip link set wlan0 up I can the interface wlan0 if I enter ifconfig. However the command cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate still returns "down". If I connect my wifi module to an access point the return value is changed to up. Why is it not "up" before ? Because I would like to test after command ip link set wlan0 up. Thank.